# Safari getUserMedia() Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, webrtc, getusermedia

As advised in internet i added the `muted` and `playsinline` attributes to my video element. I still cant get a vision in Safari 11 but only this error.
I also tried to remove `autoplay` from my video element.

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Type error`

Is it possible to get `webrtc` working in Safari 11 or am i losing time with this?

`getUserMedia()` works on all other browsers (Chrome,Firefox,Edge,Opera).

Thank you!

I use this shim, https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js/blob/gh-pages/lib/getUserMedia.js this returns a success callback,

Then in the callback,

```
var video = camOptions.videoEl; //the video element

var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

try {
    video.src = vendorURL ? vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
}
catch(err) {
    //HERE IS THE TYPE ERROR IN SAFARI
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TypeError` you are getting is because you are passing the **wrong constraints** when calling `GetUserMedia`. This error happens when you pass constrains which are not recorgnized by the device (browser) or have invalid values.

Also, you need to use `video.srcObject` and not `video.src` which is deprecated.

Here's a working example for Safari. Keep in mind this only works on iOS 11 and above:

```
// Get the <video> element
var video = document.getElementById('vid');

// Default constrains
var constraints = { audio: true, video: true };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess);

var handleSuccess = function (stream) {  
    video.srcObject = stream;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Better define handleSuccess callback before calling navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, I stuck here for some minutes.